# ActionScript throwing Error #1009 when calling addChild with a TileList as the argument

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

To be exact this is the error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.containers::BaseScrollPane/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::TileList/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

Now I've tried several of Adobe's own examples from this page, http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/TileList.html, and they all throw this error as well.

The error is triggered by the TileList instance being the argument of the addChild function.

Here's my package, which works fine when I change the displayComponent is be a List.

```
package com.pennstate {
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
    import fl.controls.List;
    import fl.controls.TileList; 

    public class Sign {
        public var displayComponent:TileList;
        public var url:String;
        public var provider:DataProvider;
        public var mc:MovieClip;
        public var container:DisplayObjectContainer;

        public function Sign( url:String, container ) {
            this.container = container;
            this.displayComponent = new TileList();
            this.mc = new MovieClip();
            this.url = url;
            this.provider = new DataProvider();

            _componentSetup();
            loadJson();
            _componentFormat();
        }

        private function _componentSetup() {
            displayComponent.labelFunction = getLabelFieldContent;
            displayComponent.sourceFunction = getSourceFieldContent;
            displayComponent.dataProvider = provider;
            displayComponent.selectable = false;
            displayComponent.setStyle("contentPadding", 5);
            displayComponent.setSize(1720,770);
            displayComponent.move(100,200);
            displayComponent.rowHeight = 190;
            trace('End setup');
        }

        private function _componentFormat() {
            var listTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            listTextFormat.font = "Arial";
            listTextFormat.color = 0x000000;
            listTextFormat.bold = true;
            listTextFormat.size = 48;
            displayComponent.setRendererStyle("textFormat", listTextFormat);
            trace('End formatting');
        }

        function loadJson():void {
            var jsonLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            jsonLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onJsonComplete);
            jsonLoader.load( new URLRequest( url ) );
        }  

        function onJsonComplete(e:Event):void {
            trace('Loading finished.');
            var jsonData:String = e.target.data;
            trace(jsonData + "\n");
            var decodedData = JSON.decode(jsonData, false);
            for (var index in decodedData.rows) {
                provider.addItem({title: decodedData.rows[index].node.title, result: decodedData.rows[index].node.Result});
                trace(index+" => "+decodedData.rows[index].node.title);
                trace(index+" => "+decodedData.rows[index].node.Result);
            }
            container.addChild(displayComponent);
        }

        function getLabelFieldContent(item:Object):String {
            return new XMLDocument(item.title + "\n" + item.result).firstChild.nodeValue;
        }

        function getSourceFieldContent(item:Object):String {
            return item.result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `public function Sign( url:String, container )` is it possible that since you're duplicating variable names it's screwing up? Try renameing the variable in the arguments to _container.

Comment: I've take the container variable out completely, same error.  Still works fine when I use a regular List instead of a TileList.  I can't even get Adobe's examples to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given your `container` agrument in the constructor a type i.e: UIComponent

```
public function Sign( url:String, container:UIComponent )
```

This coupled with the fact that its the same name as your member variable is probably the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've determined that's not related to the problem.  It didn't work before I added the container variable as argument to the class.  I've taken that factor completely out of the class anyway and it still throws the error. :(   Even Adobe's own examples throw this error and they aren't using a custom class at all.  The examples just use simple scripts.

Comment: You could try creating an AS class that extends TileList e.g. public class MyTileList extends TileList, and use the MyTileList class as the TileList for your example. Maybe its got something to do with the TileList component not being imported into the swf or something

Answer (score 0):

I had to drag an actual TileList component from the Component Menu onto the Stage using the Flash CS4 GUI to make this error go away.

The weird part is the component that I dragged onto the Stage isn't the component I use in the code.  The component I created dynamically in the code now works though.

I even deleted the TileList component that I added to the Stage and it still works.  This sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Not a bug. The component is still in your library.